# Auto incrementing column P100-001, P100-002 etc

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem

Within our SharePoint Enterprise 2013 On-Premise environment we have documents that need to be tagged with codes for example:

- Procedure Document: `P100-001`
- Forms: `F100-001`

So when a procedure document is upload I would like it to get assigned the next available code, e.g. `P100-002`.

What is the best approach for this?

EDIT: So it looks like the best solution is to use a workflow, I have created the workflow but unsure of what I need to type

[image]

Basically I want a string of text P100- and the add the item ID

Comment: I have read that using [ID} in a calculated field is unreliable. Some developers use a workflow to set and add this value on item creation: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22977/how-to-use-calculated-field-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-item-in-the-sharepoint-200

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I write the workflow?

Comment: Create an extra column ``MyID`` in your list and in a On Create Workflow write the value of ``ID`` to it. You can then use MyID savely in Formulas

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Document ID column for each document.

Follow this article: [Creating a custom Document ID provider](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-sharepoint-server-2010-creating-a-custom-document-id-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Document-ID feature or make ID in a calculated column work.
It is 0 (in Formulas) for newly created items because the ID value is generated **after** all Formulas are evaluated, so you need one Workflow to write the item ID to another column `myID`

You can then use a Calculated column

```
="PO-" & TEXT( [Created] , "yy" ) & TEXT( [MyID] , "000" )
```

If you need more fancy stuff:

[Create unique number with ListItem [ID] and [Today] age in Calculated Column Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for/160447#160447)