# SP07 - Auto_Increment Column

Tags: list, calculated-column

I have a column with name "Title " and  want to make my column be a auto increment (1, 1) with Calculated column option. How to do it ?

Comment: There is a ID column which get auto incremented by 1. Why don't you use that?

Comment: Because, I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is that use ID column. It is not possible with only calculated column option. You have to set workflow for auto increment value.

Comment: This is not for me, without WorkFlows :D

Comment: Just add ID column in list view. Go to Modify view >> Checked ID column from columns section and save it. You can visible ID column in list.

Answer (score 1):

It **is** possible with a Calculated Column,
but the Workflow method of incrementing is the **best** way to go.

If you can not do Workflows and are stuck to Calculated Columns then the full details are at:

Why you can **not** use [ID] :
[Calculated column with ID removes ID number on update](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159962/calculated-column-with-id-removes-id-number-on-update/159971#159971)

How to workaround it: 
[Create unique number with ListItem [ID] and [Today] age in Calculated Column Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for/160447#160447)

**DISCLAIMER** This is not for the faint of heart!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the auto increment value from the id field and put it in the formula field:

```
[ID]
```

[image: Place the id here]

Comment: How to do it ? I'm a beginner with SP..

Comment: added an Image thats Shows where to place it.

Comment: This is valid for SharePoint 2007 ?

Comment: and column type must be a ?

Comment: yes, and it must be a **calculated colomn Option** as was stated in your question.

Comment: Do not use the ID field within a calculated field: - You will have trouble inserting a record. It will work well in the modification. - It is not officially supported by Microsoft

Comment: do you have a reference link that you could provide to Support your claim? @jpussacq I have used this before and haven't had Problems with it

Comment: No unfortunately it is not common functionality "unsupported" are published. But ID, as Today are not recommended use in calculated fields. That is the reason why not appear in the list of available fields. You will find many articles from people who have tried them. But it is not recommended. You can always run the risk, but it's never good to use functionality not supported.

Comment: Some links with some explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173805/sharepoint-2013-calculated-field-not-working-all-the-time and http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22977/how-to-use-calculated-field-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-item-in-the-sharepoint-200

Answer (score 0):

**Alternatives**

**1) Use ID**

It is the best option because SharePoint ensures its uniqueness. But you can not apply business logic. It starts at 1 and increases by 1. You will have gaps when records are deleted.

**2) Event handler**

Create an event receiver to generate increased values according to the logic that you need. You need Visual Studio and C#.

**3) Workflow**

It can be an alternative. But workflows are not planning for it. The advantage is that you do not need to develop in C# as in option 2.

**Important**

Do not use the ID field within a calculated field:
- You will have trouble inserting a record. It will work well in the modification.
- It is not officially supported by Microsoft

If you need further assistance, please consult me.
Greetings!