# Unique Auto_generated ID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, custom-list

Is there a way to add new unique auto-generated ID for every new item added to a custom list? I would like the numbering to start at 300 as I will be uploading data to the list which already have been allocated a unique ID.

Many thanks

Comment: Im using SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

List already had an auto Id field. This starts at 1 and auto increment as new entry is added.

You can create a calculated field and use a formula like

```
= 300 + [Id]
```

Comment: Just beware that using `Id` in calculated columns is not reliable: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22977/how-to-use-calculated-field-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-item-in-the-sharepoint-200

Comment: The SharePoint auto ID is out of sync with my created ID  due to testing and deleting dummy data, so I  can use it,

Comment: Which is your SharePoint version?

Comment: Using a workflow to generate it would be more reliable, calculated columns with the ID column is horribly unreliable.

Comment: HI there,  can you tell me how to create a workflow to do this? I would like my numbering to start from 300